# What should I do if a check gets lost in the mail?

Tags: check

Should I request a new check from the sender? And is there a risk that they might not provide one?

What if something else happens, like what if the check gets damaged?

Comment: As a European, it is strange to see how people come to have the idea of sending checks by mail (or by using checks at all at the first place). Why is it in the US so unusual to send money from account to account?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, check not made available for you to deposit cannot be claimed as a payment of the obligation. I.e.: if you have never received the check, its the other party's problem to prove that they've given it to you. If they don't reissue you can sue them.

Of course, it depends on your local rules and regulations and you should ask for a legal advice on the issue.

Requesting checks to be mailed by a certified/registered mail will definitely help, as @Jontas suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer to your question, but a suggestion if a check is not lost already is to use registered mail (or whatever your local equivalent is). Using that method will cost (you) slightly more but you will not have to worry about the answers to your original question.

And in shot Registered mail is: "The posted item has its details recorded in a register to enable its location to be tracked, sometimes with added insurance to cover loss."

Also (at least here in Sweden) in order to track to whom it was handed out a photo id is required to pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

request a new check from the sender and its up to them if they decide to provide you one.

Comment: What are the chances that it might not happen, and what can I do to maximize the chances that it happens in case the check gets lost/accidentally destroyed?